# What are the keyboard shortcuts for copying login and password in 1Password without using the browser extension?

Tags: keyboard, 3rd-party, password

I am using [1Password](https://agilebits.com/products/1Password) (version 3.8.5) to manage my login data and somehow I am reluctant to use the browser extensions. I want to speed up my login and password acquisition though and therefore I am searching for **keyboard shortcuts** to:

1. Copy a password
2. Copy a login

The keyboard shortcuts for getting to the login I have searched for or for tabbing to the correct item in the UI is something I am already familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not specific keyboard shortcuts for those two individual items in [1Password](https://agilebits.com/products/1Password) but you can navigate to them with the keyboard.

Here's how you could get a login or password into your clipboard without pushing a mouse (or fondling a trackpad).

1. <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to search for the account you want to access
2. <kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd> to move up or down through the search results
3. <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> to switch to edit mode for the selected record
4. <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you get to the field you want to copy
5. <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the value from the field
6. <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> again to exit edit mode

You now have the value you want on your clipboard.

I know it's not the single shortcut you were looking for but I think it's as close as you're going to get with 1Password.

Comment: I like this approach although it is rather keyboard intensive and requires quite some effort. The only concern I have is with security. The logins and passwords are copied to the clipboard and are not cleared. If there is no other way then this will do for my needs. Thanks!

Comment: This is an OS level restriction. If you copy something it goes to the clipboard and there is no way to send any kind of auto-destruct-after-first-paste flag along with the object text. The only way to clear the clipboard of this item would be to copy something else.

Answer (score 1):

Was just searching for the exact same thing and it looks as though 1Password has had this function recently added as I found this post:
http://support.agilebits.com/discussions/1password-38-for-mac-from-agilebits-website/6681-keyboard-shortcut-to-copy-password

Option+Command+c will copy the currently selected password. Just tried it on my copy and it works great.